# Get tags with class name using XPATH

Tags: php, xpath

Below is my xml

```
<div class="image">
<img  src="">
<div class="image-text"><p class="border_style">work </p></div>
</div>
```

I want to get all the contents inside class="image-text"

output

```
<p class="border_style">work </p>
```

how can I do this using XPath? or any other way?

I've tried this,

`$image->xpath("*[@class='image-text']")`  but didn't work.

Please advice

### New

```
$i = 0;
$imageXmlParts = $xmlobject->xpath("//div[@class='block-image']");

$imageText = $xmlobject->xpath("//*[@class='block-image-text']");


foreach ( $imageText as $image ){
    echo $image->asXML().PHP_EOL;
    $out = "";
    foreach ( $image->children() as $content )  {
        $out .= $content->asXML();
    }
    echo $out.PHP_EOL;
}


foreach ($imageXmlParts as $imageXml) {

    $i++;
    $imagedata = array(
        'template'  => (string) $this->template,
        'src'           => (string) $imageXml->img['src'],

        'imagetext' => ///need to add here
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the XPath you have should get you the following...

```
$imageText = $image->xpath("//*[@class='image-text']");
echo $imageText[0]->asXML().PHP_EOL;
```

gives...

```
<div class="image-text">
        <p class="border_style">work </p>
    </div>
```

which includes the node itself.  Using `[0]` gives the first item that matches the XPath expression as `xpath()` always returns an array of matches.

If you want JUST the content, then you will have to build it up from the child nodes of the one found...

```
$out = "";
foreach ( $imageText[0]->children() as $content )  {
    $out .= $content->asXML();
}
echo $out;
```

which just gives...

```
<p class="border_style">work </p>
```

**Update:**

To add this into the code you have, I've restructured it a bit so that it starts off looking for the outer tag (I think with class called block-image) and then it loops over that.  Then it uses XPath within this element to find the text for it.

```
$imageXmlParts = $image->xpath("//*[@class='block-image']");
$imagedata = array();
foreach ( $imageXmlParts as $imageXml ){
    $text = $imageXml->xpath("descendant::div[@class='block-image-text']");
    $out = "";
    foreach ( $text[0]->children() as $content )  {
        $out .= $content->asXML();
    }
    if ( $out == "" )   {
        $out = (string)$text[0];
    }
    $imagedata[] = array(
        'template'  => (string) $this->template,
        'src'       => (string) $imageXml->img['src'],
        'imagetext' => $out
    );
}
```

**Final update:**

It may be easier to just extract the XML from the node and then remove the tags -

```
$out = $text[0]->asXML();
```

gives you...

```
<div class="block-image-text">
            <p class="border_style">work </p>
            aaaa
        </div>
```

You may be able to use  regular expression to remove the tags, but I've gone for the simple replace and chop the last part of the string off method...

```
foreach ( $imageXmlParts as $imageXml ){
    $text = $imageXml->xpath("descendant::div[@class='block-image-text']");
    $out = $text[0]->asXML();
    $out = str_replace('<div class="block-image-text">', '', $out);
    $out = substr($out, 0, -6);
    $imagedata[] = array(
        'template'  => (string) '$this->template',
        'src'       => (string) $imageXml->img['src'],
        'imagetext' => $out
    );
}
```

Comment: Do I need to initiate asXML() any where? seems im getting error

Comment: Im getting this now Call to a member function asXML() on null  @Nigel Ren

Comment: its small part. I'm storing this on db and fetching as xmlobject

Comment: I've added the test data to the answer so you can check what I'm doing.

Comment: I've updated the XPath expression to use `//` at the start, this may help with the problem.

Comment: yeah works as charm. but when there is two or more with same path return only first since we put [0] how can I loop it to return others too?

Comment: I'm just getting trouble when applying this to my existing loop. I want to add the output of looped image into 'imagetext' in array. I've updated my question with that, can help me on that?

Comment: Thanks. only issue is if the content has plain text then it wont come. Ex: <div class="block-image-text">plain text no tags </div>, any fix for tht?

Comment: I've updated the code, added `if ( $out == "" )   {...` bit

Comment: If I add any texts without wrapping with html tags it won't come. any fix for that ? pls advice Ex: <div class="image-text"><p class="border_style">work </p>texts with no html wrapps here</div>

Comment: I've added a last code update, it should get any XML inside the tags.  BUT it is a bit of a hack, but it should work.

Comment: do we need "$out = substr($out, 0, -6);" this as well ? what does that do, after replacing this str_replace('<div class="block-image-text">', '', $out)

Comment: Sorry about the delay, the `substr()` removes the `</div>` off the end of the string.